# How to use different preprocessing functions in python3 using a for loop?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, preprocessor, attributeerror

I am currently looking at `scikit learn`'s `preprocessing` functions.

I wanted to know if i can loop over a pre-defined list of pre-processing functions such that i don't have to write out in full the set up code for each function.

E.g. code for one function:

```
T = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train = T.fit_transform(X_train) 
X_test = T.transform(X_test)
```

My attempt to loop over a pre-defined list so as to use different pre-processing functions:

```
pre_proc = ['Normalizer','MaxAbsScaler','MinMaxScaler','KernelCenterer', 'StandardScaler']

     for proc in pre_proc:
         T = 'preprocessing.'+ proc +'()'
         X_train = T.fit_transform(X_train)
         X_test = T.transform(X_test)
```

Currently this is yielding the following which is not surprising:

```
-->   37    X_train = T.fit_transform(X_train)

      38    X_test = T.transform(X_test) 

      39     for i in np.arange(startpt_c,endpt_c, step_c):

      AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fit_transform'
```

I think i need to have the string as the correct object type to then call the method on i.e. have it recognised as a function.

Is there a way i can do this that satisfies my objective of using a loop?

Setup: `Windows 8`, `64 bit` machine running `Python 3` via `Jupyter notebook` in `Azure ML studio`.

Comment: Create a list of actual functions? `pre_proc = [preprocessing.Normalizer, preprocessing.MaxAbsScalar, preprocessing.MinMaxScalar, ...]` ?

Comment: Make a list of instances not names like `[Normalizer() ,MaxAbsScaler(), MinMaxScaler(), KernelCenterer(), ...]`. You can even use a `dict`  for key as names.

Comment: Also, change the names `X_test` and `X_train` inside the loop to something else, because it will then produce error on next iteration of loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this line of your code

```
pre_proc = ['Normalizer','MaxAbsScaler','MinMaxScaler','KernelCenterer', ...
```

What you are doing here is creating a list `pre_proc` that is basically just a list of strings. Python has no idea that you actually meant them to be functions. And so when you try to use `T = 'preprocessing.'+ proc +'()'` , python throws an error and say, that `T` is a string and has not method such as `fit_transform`. So instead of using strings, use the actual function names, i.e., don't put them in quotes. Use them like so -

```
pre_proc = [preprocessing.Normalizer, preprocessing.MaxAbsScalar, preprocessing.MinMaxScalar, preprocessing.KernelCenterer, preprocessing.StandardScaler]
```